# How to select unique representatives from partitions of Java HashSet

Tags: java, set, hashset

I would like to know a way to implement a scenario that I am trying to do.

I have a HashSet of Objects with Object having an attribute A of type int. Now, I want a representative from each of the distinct partitions of HashSet based on the distinct values of the attribute A.

For example:
Let the HashSet be

```
{O1, O2, O3, O4, O5, O6} where O1 to O6 are objects with attribute values as follows

Partition #1
O1.A = 1
O2.A = 1
Partition #2
O3.A = 2
O4.A = 2
O5.A = 2
Partition #3
O6.A = 3
```

I want a representative from each partition,

```
e.g. {O1, O4, O6}
```

Can anybody suggest some way to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Somnath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `Map<Integer, YourClass>` (probably best a TreeMap, so the partitions are in order), and copy the data into it:

```
 Map<Integer, YourClass> partitions = new TreeMap<Integer, YourClass>();
 for (YourClass x: set){
    Integer p = x.getA();
    if (partitions.containsKey(p))
       continue;
    partitions.put(p, x);
 }
```

After this, `partitions` contains one entry for every partition found, with one representative each (the first one found).

```
Set<YourClass> representatives = partitions.values();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a map from integer to lists of object:

```
Map<Integer, List<YourObject>> map
```

go through your set, and for an object `o` you add it to the corresponding object-list.

You then go through the map, partition by partition, and select a (random if you like) element from the list.

Here's a complete example:

```
// Setup
Set<YourObject> objs = new HashSet<YourObject>();

// Partition #1
objs.add(new YourObject("O1", 1));
objs.add(new YourObject("O2", 1));
// Partition #2
objs.add(new YourObject("O3", 2));
objs.add(new YourObject("O4", 2));
objs.add(new YourObject("O5", 2));
// Partition #3
objs.add(new YourObject("O6", 3));

// Group by A-attribute
Map<Integer, List<YourObject>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<YourObject>>();

for (YourObject o : objs) {
    if (!map.containsKey(o.A))
        map.put(o.A, new ArrayList<YourObject>());
    map.get(o.A).add(o);
}

// Select representatives:
Random rnd = new Random();
for (List<YourObject> partition : map.values()) {
    YourObject representative = partition.get(rnd.nextInt(partition.size()));
    System.out.println(representative.id);
}
```

**Output:**

```
O2
O4
O6
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to get all the results and store them into a HashMap. Since its keys are unique, you can get the values from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashSet<MyObject> inputSet; // Assuming inputSet is already initiliazed ... just put it here for clarity
HashSet<Integer> auxSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
List<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

for (MyObject o : inputSet) {
   if (!auxSet.contains(o.getA()) {
       auxSet.add(o.getA());
       result.add(o);
   }
}
```

// Now result contains your representatives